# In c++ how to insert key and value in empty map from another full map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am new  to C++.

I am making a card game using `map <int, int>`, I have `id` and `value` of the cards, and an empty map for used cards. I need to transfer the value and the key from one to the other map. Used cards is used to check for not repeating cards from map `spil`.

```
struct cards { 
    map<int, int> used_cards;
    map<int, int> card_spil = {{1, 11},{2, 2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}...}
}
// random number for dealing
a=random(); 
// see if that card is already in use
auto search = cards1.used_cards.find(a);
// if not put her id and value in used_cards map
if (search == cards1.used_cards.end()){ 
    // put id and values from card_spil to used_cards
}
```

### Question:

How to implement the block of the `if` statement?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: From an iterator you can use `first` as the key and `second` as the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert an element in `used_cards`, from `card_spil`, you can use:

```
used_cards.insert({a, card_spil.at(a)});
```

And then to delete the key->value from the `card_spil`:

```
card_spil.erase (a);
```

Comment: tenx :)))))))))))))))